# How can I scrape only word data from a website?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, web-crawler, data-mining

I want to download all the word content from a particular website. Save the results in MS Word, Excel or Notepad and check which words are repeated most often and how many times.

Comment: What have you accomplished so far?

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky - as you have to download the HTML to get to the rest.
Luckily, the problem is already solved. Use Wget.
Download (including Windows binaries) [here](http://wget.addictivecode.org/Faq#download)
and the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files)

I've given you the manual anchor for the "--accept" option, which limits the types of files saved. You'll need to mix it up with --mirror, and maybe some of the max depth options. Look out for "span hosts" if you get less information than you need.

I think that answers the question as posed - if you want help counting words, (or converting word/excel to text programmatically) that's probably a new question.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of OP's question: How to obtain *only the words*, and not HTML tags and such, from the source code.

Comment: Possibly, yes, the mention of word could be a red herring!

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to download the file, then use an HTML parser to extract the text.  The powershell command to download a webpage is:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://google.com -OutFile C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/google.html
```

That would save an html file named "google.html" on your desktop (if you change JohnDoe to your windows ID).  Then you can use an html parser on it.  Here is a link to a wikipedia comparison of html parsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers